# How can I prevent Python from automatically converting int to float when I use pow and mod?

Tags: python-3.x, rsa

I am trying to encrypt with rsa using the formula c = m^p mod q.
The Problem is if the number is too large, python3 convert it to float when doing modulo.

I tried to stop converting by converting into int

```
c = int(int((pow(n,p)) % q))
```

the problem is when p is too big it automatically has decimals and python thinks , that i am trying integer to float. Which leads to this:

```
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Don't compute `pow(n,p)` explicitly, since you're going to `mod q` it anyway.

Comment: This would seem to be a machine-dependent problem. Can you give more information related to what range of values you're using for p and q?

Comment: Are you using the built-in `pow` function or `math.pow`?

Comment: the n is 140507322219040 , p = 9391480 and q =  14961148 @krmckone

Comment: i am using the built in pow why? does it make a difference?

Comment: You can "simplify" your calculation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: If you're using the built-in `pow`, then my only guess is that one of `n`, `p`, and `q` are not integers, so the operations convert the other argument to float, causing the error.

Comment: Use the 3-argument form of pow, `pow(n, p, q)`,  for modular exponentiation. It makes more sense, and if for some reason you have imported `pow` from `math` you'll get an error.

Comment: The three argument `pow` will also raise an error if any of the arguments are not integers, which is the only other cause I can think of for this error.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem, but it does address the specific concerns you put forth in your question and suggests possible causes based on what you've told us.

---

The problem you're having isn't with `%`. As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations),

> The floor division and modulo operators are connected by the following identity: `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)`.

Given integer `x` and `y`, `(x//y)*y` is always an exact integer, so `x - (x//y)*y == x%y` must also be an integer.

---

Since you said you are using the built-in `pow` function, I suspect that your problem is that your inputs are floats instead of ints. In that case, both `pow` and `**` will try to convert the other of the argument to `float`, which could be the source of your error. If this is the case, wrapping each argument in `int` will make the error go away, but your RSA implementation will be incorrect.